# Socket.io not changing HTML

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, express, socket.io

In my Node app, I'm using Socket.io to send text to the client side. I can see that the text has successfully sent from server to client but in my client-side jQuery file, socket.io is not updating my html.

server.js:

```
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Web server up on port ${port}`);
});

let io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('Connected socket!');
});

app.post('/findbrokenlinks', (req, res) => {

    ...

    // here i'm iterating through an array of links and if they are broken, I'm sending them to the client side

    links.forEach( (linkUrl) => {
        if (isBroken(linkUrl)) {
            io.sockets.emit("result", linkUrl);
        }
    }

}
```

index.js:

```
var socket = io('ws://localhost:3000', {transports: ['websocket']});

socket.on("result", function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#results').append($('<p>').text(data));
});
```

index.hbs:

```html
<div id="results">

</div>
```

In both my node console and javascript client console, I can see that the information has been exchanged. But my webpage is stuck on loading and does not show my updated `results` div.

Here is what my client-side console (Safari Inspect Element) looks like:

```
[Log] https://gmail.com/deadlink (server.js, line 74)
[Log] https://www.facebook.com/awg;alwmg;lawkg (server.js, line 74)
[Log] https://github.com/alwfl (server.js, line 74)
> Selected Element
< <div id="results">
<p>https://gmail.com/deadlink</p>
<p>https://www.facebook.com/awg;alwmg;lawkg</p>
<p>https://github.com/alwfl</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Uhh, `for each (linkUrl in links) { ...}` isn't valid Javascript.  Perhaps you mean `for (let linkUrl of links) {...}`.

Comment: @jfriend00 You're right. I'll update that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. My webpage now updates in real-time by adding this line of code:

```js
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Web server up on port ${port}`);
});

let io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('Connected socket!');
});

app.post('/findbrokenlinks', (req, res) => {

    ...

    // here i'm iterating through an array of links and if they are broken, I'm sending them to the client side

    for each (linkUrl in links) {
        if (isBroken(linkUrl)) {
            io.sockets.emit("result", linkUrl);
        }
    }

    res.redirect('/findbrokenlinks'); // ADD THIS LINE !!

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly from your previous comments, the iteration of "searching for broken links" only occurs when the server receives a POST request, so there will most likely be no real-time updates anyways. If this behavior is intended, however, you need to call `res.end()` since you aren't calling `res.send()` to send data.

Comment: Would I still need a res.end() when I have a res.redirect() at the end of my POST request? You're correct that the searching for broken links only occurs on the POST request but somehow, I *am* getting real-time updates after I added the res.redirect ... ?

Comment: res.redirect() calls res.end() itself, there would be no reason to call res.end() again. Do you have an app.get('/findbrokenlinks', ()) route setup as well to respond to the request?

Comment: Yes, I have an app.get('/findbrokenlinks', ... ) set up

Comment: Anyways, glad you figured it out!

Comment: Thanks for your responses :)